# knockout js update visibility based in property value

Tags: knockout.js

I am loading data from a web API like this:

```
$.getJSON("/api/Rule", function (rules) {
    self.Rules(rules);
});
```

Then I bind `Rules` to a table using a foreach binding.  Each `Rule` has the properties: `Keyword`, `Attribute`, and `Value`.

I want to check if `Keyword` is a certain value which controls the visibility of some controls.

```
data-bind="options: viewModel.Attributes, visible : Keyword != 'Else'"
```

The problem is the visibility is not updating when I change the value of `Keyword` to a different value.

How do I get this to work?

If it is supposed to be through some kind of binding, I did not declare a special object in my view model and I am just using whatever was returned from the server.

Comment: Checkout the Knockout mapping plugin: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html This will help you in creating an observable from Json data. Also make sure to check if you need Keyword or Keyword(). I would add a span with a data-bind="text: Keyword" so you can check what the value is. I will post a more complete answer when I have more time

Comment: @WouterdeKort I did place a span and I dont see that the Keyword value isnt updating. Using Keyword() doesnt work either. It throws an error "function expected". I am guessing you cannot use that inside the data-bind settings.

Comment: Update: I created an object exactly the same as the object that my Web Api returns called Rule and instead of just setting the values like above, I did a $.each on the data I get back and created a collection of KO objects manually and then I am able to see that the value gets updated immadieatly after I tab off. How can I do this without creating an object in KO which is kind of duplicate/redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, you *must* map your objects to observables. That's how knockout is able to do its magic.  Using the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) will make this trivial.

```
$.getJSON("/api/Rule", function (rules) {
    var mappedRules = ko.mapping.fromJS(rules);
    self.Rules(mappedRules);
});
```

Otherwise you can map it yourself.

```
$.getJSON("/api/Rule", function (rules) {
    var mappedRules = ko.utils.arrayMap(rules, function (rule) {
        return {
            Keyword: ko.observable(rule.Keyword),
            Attribute: ko.observable(rule.Attribute),
            Value: ko.observable(rule.Value)
        };
    });
    self.Rules(mappedRules);
});
```

Just remember that you are now dealing with observables now so you need to adjust your bindings.

```
data-bind="options: viewModel.Attributes, visible : Keyword() != 'Else'"
```